# duration of two datepickers in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

hi am trying to get difference between two `datepickers` in bootstrap I have tried below code but it is not giving any output i have three text boxes in first text box is current time second is 4 hours addition to current time in third text box i need difference i.e., duration.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srknthcse/CujDK/335/)

**HTML**

```
   <input type="text" id="datetimepicker-duration"  readonly> </input> 

 </div>

  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var hours = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();
$(function () {
    $('#startdatetime-from').datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
        pick12HourFormat: 'true',
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate:new Date(),
        format: 'HH:mm PP dd-MM-yyyy '
    });
    $("#startdatetime-from").data('datetimepicker').setLocalDate(new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes));

    $('#startdatetime-from1').datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
        pick12HourFormat: 'true',
        startDate : new Date(),
        format: 'HH:mm PP dd-MM-yyyy ' 
    });

    $("#startdatetime-from1").data('datetimepicker').setLocalDate(new Date(year, month, day, hours+4, minutes) );


    var d1 = $('#startdatetime-from').datepicker('getDate');
    var d2 = $('#startdatetime-from1').datepicker('getDate');
    var diff = 0;
      if (d1 && d2) {
            diff = Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day
      }
    $("#duration").data('diff').setLocalDate(new Date());

    });
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: also available on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/srknthcse/CujDK/335/

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CujDK/351/)

I have added the following code

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var hours = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();
$(function () {
    $('#startdatetime-from').datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
        pick12HourFormat: 'true',
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate: new Date(),
        format: 'HH:mm PP dd-MM-yyyy ',

    });
    $("#startdatetime-from").data('datetimepicker').setLocalDate(new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes));

    $('#startdatetime-from1').datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
        pick12HourFormat: 'true',
        startDate: new Date(),
        format: 'HH:mm PP dd-MM-yyyy '
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        $("#datetimepicker-duration").val(getDt());
    });

    $("#startdatetime-from1").data('datetimepicker').setLocalDate(new Date(year, month, day, hours + 4, minutes));

    $('#duration').datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
        pick12HourFormat: 'true',
        startDate: new Date(),
        format: 'HH:mm PP dd-MM-yyyy '
    });

    $("#duration").data('datetimepicker').setLocalDate(new Date(year, month, day, hours + 4, minutes));

    function getDt() {

        var d1 = $('#startdatetime-from').data('datetimepicker').getDate(); //"now"
        var d2 = $('#startdatetime-from1').data('datetimepicker').getDate(); // some date
        var diff = Math.abs(d2 - d1);
        diff = msToTime(diff);
        alert(diff);
        return diff;
    }

    function msToTime(duration) {

        var milliseconds = parseInt((duration % 1000) / 100);
        var seconds = (duration / 1000) | 0;
        duration -= seconds * 1000;

        var minutes = (seconds / 60) | 0;
        seconds -= minutes * 60;

        var hours = (minutes / 60) | 0;
        minutes -= hours * 60;

        var days = (hours / 24) | 0;
        hours -= days * 24;

        var weeks = (days / 7) | 0;
        days -= weeks * 7;
        return weeks+" Weeks "+days + " Days " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + milliseconds;
    }
    debugger
    $("#datetimepicker-duration").val(getDt());
    $("#startdatetime-from1").data('datetimepicker').keypress(function (e) {
        alert();
        $("#datetimepicker-duration").val(getDt());
    });
    $("#startdatetime-from").data('datetimepicker').keypress(function (e) {
        alert();
        $("#datetimepicker-duration").val(getDt());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for help sukanya ; if i change time and date am not able to see that change in duration text box i have tried with yes or no dialog boxes but it is not showing . it only showing 4 hours as you did please check once thank you